# I can't see the result of silhouette plot except for the axis(in R)

Tags: r, silhouette

everyone. 
I have a problem in plotting silhouette chart in R.

It is my code.

```
#k-means clustering
#install.packages("cluster")
library(cluster)
kc <- kmeans(nsoap, centers=3)

dissE <- daisy(nsoap)
sk <- silhouette(kc$cl,dissE)

plot(sk)
dev.off()
```

I just got this result. It is without the contents...

[image]

How can I overcome this problem?

Thank you:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make silhouette plot legible for k-means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570693/make-silhouette-plot-legible-for-k-means)

Answer (score 9):

Posting answer as this was the top result for a google search on this problem.

This is an issue with how the plot is rendered in RStudio.

This post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34404740/7687105) shows how to set border = NA in the call to plot() to cause the plot to render correctly.

Another option used here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34110332/7687105) is to call windows() in RStudio to get a separate window for graphics that plots the Silhouette Coefficients correctly without using the *border=* option.

Comment: Only the second option works when trying to plot the banner plot of `agnes()` with `plot(..., which.plots=1)`.

Answer (score -1):

Try it with the argument `col = "darkblue"`. For example:

```
plot(sk, col="darkblue")
```

and then you will see the plot in light color if you focus your sigth.